# How to log which process is printing?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, printing, windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer

I have Windows 2008 R2 server which has an Epson Docket Printer driver installed on it.  The server is running Remote Desktop Services, and mostly runs point of sale terminals who are using Epson docket printers.

When users login to remote desktop services, the Epson print driver sends a job to the default printer.  The printer in general completely ignores the print job and prints nothing.

In the case of clients who only have a OneNote or PDF printer installed, the job is sent through to their clients via printer redirection and they're presented with a popup asking them to "Save" the blank PDF somewhere.  The job is sent periodically, making it extremely annoying for users logging in to this system who do not have a real printer configured as their default.

My question is, is it possible to discover which process is triggering the print job and put a stop to it?  Is there an easy way to determine where the phantom print job is originating from?

Answer (score 1):

Enable

> Log spooler information events

in gpo

also check this print logging software:

http://www.papercut.com/products/free_software/print_logger/